# How can I refactor this code to mitigate an N+1 query issue using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to understand if there's an efficient way to mitigate an N+1 query problem in this particular circumstance with Eloquent. The context is that I'm currently building an API using Laravel 8.

### Summary

For the purpose of this question, the example is `Store` -> has many -> `Orders` -> many-to-many -> `Products`, ie: a store has many orders, an order has many products, but a product can belong to many different stores. There is a `product_orders` pivot table, which also tracks a couple of additional values such as `unit_price` and `quantity` etc.

My goal is to create an API endpoint which lists all of a store's orders with the products that were on that particular order.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "6531a4d4-b066-4673-ad59-8b4a49c0d675",
            "object": "order",
            "comments": "Sequi perspiciatis quasi dolorum rerum. Rem dolore nihil sint magnam totam explicabo. Non officia est ut inventore modi.",
            "order_items": [
                {
                    "product_id": "3c6400f5-fde9-47cb-ad05-ef164e00583e",
                    "product_name": "omnis inventore",
                    "unit_price": "17.15",
                    "quantity": 8
                },
                {
                    "product_id": "c208c8dd-df71-4331-909d-0615ec763555",
                    "product_name": "accusantium omnis",
                    "unit_price": "81.88",
                    "quantity": 3
                },
                {
                    "product_id": "05129518-882b-4558-b68f-df06c804a6d3",
                    "product_name": "voluptatem vitae",
                    "unit_price": "52.58",
                    "quantity": 4
                },
            ],
            "supplier_invoice_no": ABC1234,
        }
    ],
    }
}
```

For this task, I'm leveraging Eloquent API resources, so my code is as follows:

#### routes/api.php

```
Route::apiResource('/stores/{store}/orders', 'Api\Stores\StoreOrderController');
```

#### StoreOrderController.php

I'm retrieving the `Store` model using a Route Model binding.

```php
public function index(Store $store)
    {
        return StoreOrdersResource::collection($store->orders);
    }
```

#### StoreOrdersResource.php

And this API resource is filtering the JSON response to just the relevant data, and this is where my issue lies I believe. For each `Order` passed through this `StoreOrdersResource` I'm retrieving `$this->products` aka `$order->products`, so a duplicate query is made, querying the Order's products for every one of the Store's orders.

```php
 public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'                    => $this->id,
            'object'                => "order",
            'comments'              => $this->comments,
            'order_items'           => $this->products,
            'supplier_invoice_no'   => $this->supplier_invoice_no,
        ];
    }
```

Perhaps there's a better way of writing this full-stop, but my assumption is that I'll have to somehow pull the Store's Orders *with* their related products, without pulling *all* Orders, or *all* products.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid additional queries you can load relations in your controller. Something like

```
// Models/Order.php
public function items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
                ->withPivot('unit_price', 'quantity');
}


// StoreOrderController.php
public function index(Store $store)
{
    $store->load('orders.items');

    return StoreOrdersResource::collection($store->orders);
}

// StoreOrdersResource.php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        // ...
        'order_items' => $this->items,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, now that I read about 'Lazy' Eager Loading it's all clicked. For your reference, I was able to leverage just the `$store->load('orders.products');` without the `buildOrderItems` function, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I am glad to help.